# SVG not opening with inkscape command line but opens with gui

Tags: svg, command-line, inkscape

I am quite new to inkscape and I would like to process a batch of SVGs using the command line interface with the following command (in the same directory as the SVG):

```
$ inkscape -D -z NMY.svg
```

However, when I try to load an SVG with the CLI I get the following warning:

```
** (inkscape-bin:8875): WARNING **: Can't open file: NMY.svg (doesn't exist)

** (inkscape-bin:8875): WARNING **: Can't open file: NMY.svg (doesn't exist)

** (inkscape-bin:8875): WARNING **: Specified document NMY.svg cannot be opened (does not exist or not a valid SVG file)
```

However, opening the same SVG from the GUI properly displays the image.

Here is the header SVG in question in case there is something wrong with it:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>
<svg version='1.1' baseProfile='full'
          xmlns:svg='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
                  xmlns:rdkit='http://www.rdkit.org/xml'
                  xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
              xml:space='preserve'
width='250px' height='150px' >
```

I am using inkscape `Inkscape 0.92.2 5c3e80d, 2017-08-06` on MacOS 10.14.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the problem, I had to specify the absolute path to the file.

Comment: Thank you so much for this.

Comment: For completeness, if you're doing an export (`-e`) the path there needs to be absolute, also.